# Ruby concatenating strings in sql query

Tags: sql, ruby, json, string, mysql2

I am getting the following output

```
INSERT INTO AIRPORTS VALUES(null, #{iata} , #{latitude} , #{longitude}, #{name}, #{city})airportsScript.rb:27:in `query': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 (Mysql2::Error)
    from airportsScript.rb:27:in `block in getAirports'
    from airportsScript.rb:20:in `each'
    from airportsScript.rb:20:in `getAirports'
    from airportsScript.rb:32:in `<main>'
```

From this script (actually complete script):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby 

require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'rest-client' 
require 'uri'
require 'mysql2'


def getAirports()

client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "****", :password => "****" , :database => "****")

  url='https://api.flightstats.com/flex/airports/rest/v1/json/all?appId=APPIDHIDENKey=KEYHIDDEN'
  airportsJson = JSON.parse(RestClient.get(url))
  for airports in airportsJson["airports"]
          iata = airports["iata"]
          latitude = airports["latitude"]
          longitude = airports["longitude"]
          name = airports["name"]
          city = airports["city"]
          print        'INSERT INTO AIRPORTS VALUES(null, #{iata} , #{latitude} , #{longitude}, #{name}, #{city})'
          client.query('INSERT INTO AIRPORTS VALUES(null, #{iata} , #{latitude} , #{longitude}, #{name}, #{city})')
  end
  client.close
end

getAirports()
```

As you may notice, in the output the first line comes from print        `'INSERT INTO AIRPORTS VALUES(null, #{iata} , #{latitude} , #{longitude}, #{name}, #{city})'` why cant i get the values of the iata, latitude, long, etc. variables instead of that actually string "#{iata}"

I am new to ruby this is my first script btw.

Comment: I don't know what are you using this script for but constructing SQL queries like that is very unsafe. You are prone to SQL injection and other problems.

Comment: i will only fill a database with a lot of flights data, just once.

Comment: Doesn't matter if it is just once. You should be properly quoting and escaping your strings. Or better, mysql2 can't possibly be so utterly broken and useless as to not support some sort of placeholders in queries, use them.

Comment: I will do the research, thank you

Comment: Apparently it is [that useless](http://rubydoc.info/github/brianmario/mysql2/frames), there doesn't seem to be any placeholder support at all. Wow. At least there's an [`escape`](http://rubydoc.info/github/brianmario/mysql2/Mysql2/Client:escape) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "double quotes" instead of 'single quotes' to interpolate variables.

```
2.0.0-p353 :001 > var = "foo"
 => "foo" 
2.0.0-p353 :002 > 'Hello #{var}'
 => "Hello \#{var}" 
2.0.0-p353 :003 > "Hello #{var}"
 => "Hello foo"
```